# Can any of my consumer take the messages from queue?

Tags: activemq-classic

I am developing an app. and I am using activemq. Is there any way to do that one producer always send messages to one broker but on the opposite side there 3 consumers.Each consumer listens broker and can take any of message from queue.Is this possible?

I am using activemq for writing my app. logs to db.As u know writing logs to db is time taking process.That's why consumer is more and more slow than producer.For ex. I send 100.000 message(huge objects).Producer finishes sending messages in 20 mins.But When the producer finished, consumer has finished 4.000 message processing yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are describing is possible. In fact, you can have any number of consumers listening on a single queue. The messages are dispatched in a round-robin fashion between consumers.

What you should be aware of is that ActiveMQ performs much better sending small messages than large ones. If you need to send very large payloads (e.g. 100mb), you are far better off saving the message to a location that is accessible by both the producer and consumers (e.g. a network file system), and sending the location of the message instead. The consumer can then use that to read the message manually. This way you get a relatively small amount of traffic through the message broker.